# What does std::numeric_limits do for types that don't specialize it?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, numeric-limits

This code [compiles and runs](https://godbolt.org/z/f7vaKh7P8)

```cpp
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int x;
};

static_assert(!std::numeric_limits<Foo>::is_specialized);

int main() {
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<Foo>::lowest().x << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<Foo>::min().x << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<Foo>::max().x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
}
```

and it prints

```
---
0
0
0
---
```

Where are those numbers coming from?

[On cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) I read that

> This information is provided via specializations of the `std::numeric_limits` template. The standard library makes available specializations for all arithmetic types

from which I'd deduce that the absence of a specialization for a given type `Foo` means that I'm not allowed to use it for `Foo`. So is the above output just a manifestation of UB? Or what?

If I change `int` to `char` in the code above, the output is

```
---
---
```

which to me is *"What?! Where have the `std::endl`s gone, to start with???"*

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/lowest - and there you see: *Return value: `/* non-specialized */ T()`*.

Comment: Note you did not initialize `x` anywhere. So '0' is just lucky, for the rest limits just returns a new instance of Foo

Comment: Make your own `numeric_limits` for your `Foo` in your own (e.g.) `namespace Enlico`.  When `x` is `char`, use `+std::numeric_limits<Foo>::min().x` to print the character as a numeric.

Comment: @PepijnKramer, and the two `---` lines I guess from uninitialized `char`? Should I assume the lucky value is being a backspace that neutralizes the `std::endl`?

Comment: @Eljay, what you mean by "in your own namespace"? `numeric_limits` lives in `std`, so isn't it there that I need to specialize it?

Comment: @PepijnKramer it's not uninitialized. The aggregate class Foo is value initialized, which value initializes the member. @Enlico you can minimize the latter example to `std::cout << char() << std::endl;`. I recommend asking about it in a separate question.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Compiler implementations are allowed (required?) to extend `std::numeric_limits` for their own types that they add to the language.  I do not believe `std::numeric_limits` is an allowed extension point for user-defined types.  You'd need your own `numeric_limits` in your own `namespace` (unless I'm mistaken, and it is one of the very few UDT extension points).

Comment: @Eljay cppreference reads: *Non-standard libraries may add specializations for library-provided types.*

Comment: @Evg • ahh, thanks for finding that!  I stand corrected.  I'd consider my own code (or Enlico's code) to be a "library" in that context.

Comment: @eerorika I must have missed that, since documentation states : T() not T{}

Comment: The specialisation for `char` returns `char` values, which are streamed differently from numbers.  You don't say how you captured the output, but perhaps something is interpreting the values (likely `\0\n` and `\377\n` if `char` is unsigned; `\200\n` and `\177\n` if signed, if you have 8-bit `char`).  Pipe into `od` or similar to find what you're actually producing.

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes, but I just type `cout` and press F8, can't go thought the hassle of removing stuff irrelevant to the question, ahahah.

Comment: @Enlico -- if pressing F8 produces incorrect code, stop pressing F8. You're in charge of the code you write; don't let your tools make decisions for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary template of `std::numeric_limits` value-initializes all members or return values from member functions, see [[numeric.limits.general]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/numeric.limits.general#3). So that is what you get if the template isn't specialized for the provided type. There is no UB.

Any specialization should set `is_specialized` to `true` and must define all members, with sensible values where applicable, or `0` or `false` otherwise, see [[numeric.limits.special]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/numeric.special#1) and [[numeric.limits.general]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/numeric.limits.general#4).

Interestingly [[numeric.limits.general]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/numeric.limits#general-4) requires the standard specializations to set `is_specialized` to `true`, but I don't see any equivalent requirement for user specializations.

Comment: I'd suggest that, if a program explicitly specialises `std::numeric_limits` for a non-standard type, it would be appropriate that specialisation set `is_specialized` to be `true`.      Pragmatically, it would be reasonable to suggest that would be "meaningful" in the sense of your second link (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/numeric.special#1 ).   Certainly, it would be reasonable to question the utility of such an explicit specialisation which did *not* do that.

Answer (score 6):

Using the unspecialized `numeric_limits` is well defined. The code example has no UB. Quote from the standard draft:

> ```
> ...
> static constexpr T min() noexcept { return T(); }
> static constexpr T max() noexcept { return T(); }
> static constexpr T lowest() noexcept { return T(); }
> ...
> ```
>
> For the `numeric_limits` primary template, all data members are value-initialized and all member functions return a value-initialized object.
>
> [*Note 1*: This means all members have zero or `false` values unless `numeric_limits` is specialized for a type. - *end note*]

- [[numeric.limits.general] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/numeric.limits.general#3)